# Address as name of an array in solidity?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, blockchain, remix

How to make an array with its name as address of user?

For example `string[]` public `0x7v77wfr349C9864De0119E94c3f8d`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because variable names can't begin with a number in solidity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, provided you prepend a string (which be alphabetic).

For instance you can have a variable named:

ACC0x7v77wfr349C9864De0119E94c3f8d

or

Ox7v77wfr349C9864De0119E94c3f8d

(beware: the first character is not zero, but the letter O.

On the other hand, it is very difficult to find a case where this is truly useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one or two users, then:

```
string[] public aliceArray;
string[] public bobArray;
```

But I suspect you are looking for something like:

```
mapping(address => string[]) everyoneArray;
```

Every possible user address has a corresponding dynamic array of strings.

You specify elements like:

```
everyoneArray[<address>][<row>];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot declare a variable dynamically that way**.